# Using Binding.Source without using resources

Tags: wpf

I've got the following code that works well :

```
<Viewbox.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="viewSource"
                          Source="{Binding Path=SelectionList}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Viewbox.Resources>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=viewSource}}"/>
```

I would like to put my CollectionViewSource directly in my ComboBox without using any resource like that :

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=SelectionList}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

But this way my ComboBox is always empty, and I get the following binding error :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=SelectionList; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=1374711); target property is 'Source'
>   (type 'Object')

Does anyone know how could I do it ?

Comment: It's just a guess, but you may have to explicitly set the Source of the CollectionViewSource.Source's binding: `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source=... Path=SelectionList}"`. Do you see any binding error messages?

Comment: Thanks to your remark I checked my binding errors. In your suggestion what could I put in Source=...

Comment: Set it to the object that owns the SelectionList property.

Comment: SelectionList is defined in the ViewModel/DataContext. I tried <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Source=., Path=Items}"> but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicolas By explicit, I think he means an non-binding source, such as `{RelativeSource Self}`, then bind to the `DataContext.SelectionList` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicolas, although this is not an answer to your question because it still uses resources, you could put the CollectionViewSource inside the ComboBox by defining it in its local resource dictionary:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="viewSource" Source="{Binding Path=SelectionList}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewSource}"/>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @H.B. This answer has been edited significantly and the comment refers to the old answer. The old solution did indeed not work.

Comment: To summarize: the CollectionViewSource doesn't know the DataContext and there is no way to give it to him the DataContext because the CollectionViewSource is not in the VisualTree. So the only way is to use the Resources. Clemens and @Rachel, thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because the `CollectionViewSource` doesn't have a parent from which to inherit a `DataContext` from to use in the Binding.

You don't need to use a `CollectionViewSource` for your ComboBox though. You can bind it's item source to any collection by binding the `ItemsSource` property

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectionList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The only thing missing would be the sorting, however you can sort the data in your ViewModel before returning it to the View.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really need to sort in my view, not in my ViewModel, that's why I use a CollectionViewSource. Could you tell me why it works in the resource and not inside the ComboBox.

Comment: @Nicolas It works as a resource because the `Binding.Source` property is pointing to an object that has been already defined in the UI. Also, you cannot use bindings on a property that is not a `DependencyProperty`, and I don't think `Binding.Source` is a `DependencyProperty`. There's nothing wrong with making a property that returns a sorted `CollectionViewSource` from the ViewModel based on your original collection.

Comment: @Rachel, it's not a Binding's Source that is set here, but a CollectionViewSource's Source.

Comment: @Clemens Oh right, forgot about that :) In that case, it's not working because the `CollectionViewSource` is not part of the visual or logical trees, so has no parent from which to inherit a DataContext from to use in the binding. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Rachel Right, that's why the CollectionViewSource.Source's binding needs an explicit Source setting, namely to the object that owns the SelectionList property.

Comment: @Rachel: The thing about the trees is not the actual reason, after all it works in the resources and the `CollectionViewSource` still is not in any tree.

Comment: @HB Isn't it part of the main UI though if it's defined in the `resources`? As opposed to being created when needed and not part of any tree?

Comment: @Rachel: I am not entirely sure how this is being handled, when defined as a resource the binding is only resolved when the resource is referenced, and in both cases there is no tree. However in the resources there potentially could be an inheritance context while inside the binding there is not as bindings are not DependencyObjects. (Also: The dots, don't forget them, the message system is picky)